# Are IP addresses for DNS cached?

Tags: domain-name-system

I would like to create home test server.

I have static IP and I used http://www.freedns.ws/ service to get dns names.

WiFi-router routes the request on my PC and the web-site is works perfect.

But I have a problem. If I turn off server for one night website doesn't work then about several hours.

Does dns servers check accessibility of my IP and how ofter they do that?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with a professional setup?

Comment: Sorry? I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: Drew hints at the fact that your question is not [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) in this StackExchange forum.

Comment: Why this question got so many downvotes? Why it could be non on-topic? I didn't know about TTL and NooJ really helped me

Comment: Have a read of the on-topic link, there's plenty if useful information that will make it much more clear for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I'm going under the assumption that when you turn off your web server, it is no longer accessible by DNS name FreeDNS Service (ie www.mywebsite.com )

In this case it is quite normal since FreeDNS only translate your Fixed IP address 
in domain name.

It may be that you acces to your website some time as the information remains in the cache of your browser, but in no case FreeDNS will host your website, your server must remain on.

Comment: I mean I turn server off for six hours for example. Then I turn it on and website will be accessible only if 4-6 hours are passed.

Comment: The expiration time value is controlled by FreeDNS. In FreeDNS the cache values (called a TTL, time to live) are set to, let's say 3600 seconds by default (1 hour). If you dynamically update a record, it's TTL will then be adjusted to 60 seconds for faster propagation. You won't benefit from it until the next real lookup happens.